# What is the probability that out of $3$ points on an interval $[0,1]$, the first point is closest to an end point on the interval?

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry, geometric-probability

So I did this question in $2D$ first and found that out of two points, say $x$ and $y$, the probability that the $x$ is closer to $1$ is half and that the probability that the $x$ is closer $0$ is also half. I did this via the unit square.

Now if I want to do this for $3$ points, the probability space would become a unit cube but I can't quite figure out what the resulting shape would look like.

My thought was that the unit cube would be cut by planes where $x=y$ and $x=z$ such that only the portions below these planes would be chosen for the case where $x$ is closer to $1$.

If we cut with one plane, it would become a right triangular prism and the volume (probability) becomes half but I don't know what would happen to volume if I cut the right prism again.

Maybe there is a better way of solving this question.

Thanks.

Comment: As stated, the answer is $\frac 13$, by symmetry.  Each of the three points is equally likely to be nearest an endpoint.

Comment: I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: The part of the unit cube with $x<y$ and $x<z$ is a pyramid, having as base the square face at $x=0$ and as vertex the point $(1,1,1)$. Its volume is of course $1/3$.

Comment: Ah I get it. Thank you!